# ControlsFx Issue when running the jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, classnotfoundexception, controlsfx

I am looking for some help using ControlsFx library in my application. I am a beginner at this so please don't hesitate to ask me further details.

- I am using is Intellij IDEA as IDE, and I am creating a runnable jar with the artifact tool from IntelliJ.
- I am compiling with jdk 1.8.0
- Also, I am using javafx sdk 16
- And now I want to use ControlsFx so I can have autocompletion on my TextField. I have downloaded both the class and the source jar controlsfx 11.0.3 . I have put them into my classpath and sourcepath and also into the artifact dependencies.

And when I try to run the application, I have this error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/controlsfx/control/textfield/TextFields
```

Which seems to have been caused by :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 44 more
```

I hope you can help me find a solution to fix this issue.

**EDIT** : I have found https://gist.github.com/Faoc/2093cf14c91033668b2e that helps doing that in another way.

Comment: Try to use [ControlsFX 8.40.18](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/8.40.18) with JDK 1.8 (JavaFX 8 included) or upgrade to e. g. [JDK 16.0.2](http://jdk.java.net/16/) with [JavaFX 16](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) with [ControlsFX 11.1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx/11.1.0).

Comment: @anko Thank you, but I have found another way to my purpose : see https://gist.github.com/Faoc/2093cf14c91033668b2e .